# Can't validate username and password from mongodb using php

Tags: php, angularjs, mongodb

[image]I want to validate username and password from mongodb. If the username & password matches with my php code, it should advance me to admin page.
Angular validation is working for username and password but no mongodb db.
can you tell where am I making mistake?

index.php

```
 <?php 
 include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
 ?> 
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>LoginIN</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script> 


 </head> 
 <body ng-app="postAngular" ng-controller="PostController as postCtrl">

 <div id="wrapper">
  <header id="top">
  <center><h1>Leave Reporting System</h1></center>
    <div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="postCtrl.postForm()">
   <ul>
  <?php if(isset($errorMessage)):?>

   <?php endif ?>

   <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="postCtrl.inputData.username" required >


     <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required ng-model="postCtrl.inputData.password">

      <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="remember" name ="remember">Remember me
     </label><br>
     </div>

   <div  role="alert" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</div>
    <input name="login" button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  type ="submit" value=" Log in">

       <br>
       <a href="">Forgot your password?</a> 
     </ul>
 </form>

    </div>
  </body>
   </html>
```

login.php

```
<?php

$errorMessage ="";
//session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $usr = $_POST['username']; 
  $pass = $_POST['password'];

  $conn = new MongoClient();

  $db = $conn->lrs;
  $col = $db->Login;

  $query = array(
    'username' => $usr,
    'password' => md5($pass)
  );

  $cursor = $col->findOne($query);

  foreach($cursor as $obj){
    $foundusr = $obj['username'];
    $foundpass = $obj['password'];

    if($obj['username']== $usr && $obj['password']= $pass){
      header('location: admin.php');
    } else {
      $errorMessage = "<h3>Username/password did not match.</h3>";
    }
  }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$query = array(
  'username' => $usr,
  'password' => md5($pass)
);
```

You are querying the password with md5, but you are storing it in plain text!

Also md5 isn't a good security hash to store password.
Since PHP 5.5 you have password_hash() that you should use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I tried with that one also, but still not working. the problem is validation, as without using form action, it is not validating with the username and password and no navigation is also admin.php is working

Comment: Did the `$cursor` have anything? I don't think it's going to match anything. Assuming you have some constraint in 'username' field, why don't you query only by username, and then, if the user exists, you hash the password that you receive and compare with the one that you have stored.

Comment: Another thing you should be aware that the MongoDB Driver that you are using is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php and it's not compatible with PHP7